# camel stream closed error in rest service csv reader

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have to read a csv file, when i invoke a camel rest service url (with SpringBoot):

http://localhost:8080/camel/csv

This is the route builder:

```
@Component
    public class CamelContextConf extends RouteBuilder{

         static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CamelContextConf.class);

        @Override
        /**
         * http://localhost:8080/camel/csv           
          */
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            restConfiguration().component("servlet");
            rest("/csv").get().to("direct:csvprocessor");

            CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
            csv.setDelimiter(";");  
            csv.setSkipHeaderRecord(true);  

            from("direct:csvprocessor")
            .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=sample-data.csv&noop=true")
            //.split(body().tokenize("\\n"))
            .unmarshal(csv)
            .to("bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData").endRest();

            logger.info("** Route config ok");
        }
}
```

This is the handler:

```
@Component
public class MyCsvHandler {

    public void doHandleCsvData(List<List<String>> csvData)
    {
        int i = 1;
        for (List<String> rows : csvData){
            System.out.println("Riga:  " + (i++));
            for (String column :  rows){
                 System.out.print(column + " ; ");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I have to set the camel servlet endpoint in this class

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"... list of"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebApplicationAware extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Class<WebApplicationAware> applicationClass = WebApplicationAware.class;

     static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebApplicationAware.class);

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(applicationClass);
        }

        @Bean 
       public ServletRegistrationBean camelServletRegistrationBean() { 
             ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "/camel/*"); 
             registration.setName("CamelServlet"); 
             logger.info("** CamelServlet initialized..");
             return registration; 
         } 

}
```

but it give me this error when i invoke the rest route by browser:

```
08/2017 17:02:34.104 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] - org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet: Initialized CamelHttpTransportServlet[name=CamelServlet, contextPath=]
22/08/2017 17:02:34.196 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] - org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet: Error processing request
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.copyStream(DefaultHttpBinding.java:427)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteDirectResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:491)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:390)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.writeResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:322)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:210)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22/08/2017 17:02:34.198 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[CamelServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [CamelServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.copyStream(DefaultHttpBinding.java:427)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteDirectResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:491)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:390)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.writeResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:322)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:210)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22/08/2017 17:02:34.215 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
22/08/2017 17:02:34.216 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
22/08/2017 17:02:34.271 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 54 ms
22/08/2017 17:18:03.326 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] - org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet: Error processing request
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.copyStream(DefaultHttpBinding.java:427)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteDirectResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:491)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:390)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.writeResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:322)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:210)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22/08/2017 17:18:03.328 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[CamelServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [CamelServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Stream closed...
```

why ? Whats the problem?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Well the stacktrace is saying the path is empty.." context with path [] threw exception". You sure you hitting the right path?

Comment: @Sourciance Eqdam Rashti what you mean for hitting the right path? The csv path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to enrich the message you can use the `.pollEnrich()` from the Java DSL like this:

```
from("direct:csvprocessor")
.pollEnrich("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=sample-data.csv&noop=true&idempotent=false")
...
```

### UPDATE

If you would like to read the same file again and again then you could use 
`.pollEnrich("file://mydir?fileName=test.csv&noop=true&idempotent=false")` and in this sample (it's based on your first post) the route sends back HTTP 200 OK with the string "ok" if there wasn't any exception during the processing.

```
from("direct:csvprocessor")
.pollEnrich("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=sample-data.csv&noop=true&idempotent=false")
.unmarshal(csv)
.to("bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData")
.setBody(constant("ok"))
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200));
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, stream closed again.. I suppose there is a problem with the camel servlet. any suggestion? I've tried to eliminate the "to" route but the problem is the same..

Comment: Ohh, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer to meet with your requirement! Does it solve your issue?

Comment: ok i add context path and binding mode so Exception desappear..
restConfiguration().component("servlet").contextPath("afsiss").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

but when i enter in a bean myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData

the input parameter List<List<String>> csvData is empty!..

Comment: public void configure() throws Exception {
..
  from("direct:csvprocessor")
  .streamCaching()
  .from("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=sample-data.csv&noop=true")
  .unmarshal(csv)
  .to("bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData").endRest();
from used twice because route "to" deletes my files.. is it right? I have to read from csv and print to console the content for now..

Comment: yes, now it works only the first time when put http://localhost:8080/camel/csv on browser.. why can't reapeat reading each time?

Comment: Add `idempotent=false` to the properties. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Added a full sample which returns HTTP 200 OK and "ok" string message after it had read and processed the csv successfully.

Comment: Thanks it works! http://camel.apache.org/etl-example.html is good example to understanding idempotent?

Comment: I think [this](http://freecontent.manning.com/camel-in-action-idempotency/) free chapter from the Camel In Action 2 book is better and deeper!

Comment: Sorry but pollEnrich seems pool one file at a time (so i have to send request more times but i dont know files numbers..maybe using an aggregator is the wrong choiche (i have not to merge files).... ??